# Can you obtain the USERID and Host-PC name from inside a VM

Tags: c#, console, virtual-machine

The software I am working at designing will be run inside of a VM, in most(if not all) cases Micrososft Virtual PC

I am trying to find a way to record who uses the software. Seeing as all of the VM's will be logged in as an anon admin, I was thinking of pulling the logged in username/pcname from the host machine.

code base will be in C#, console application.

Is this possible.... and does anyone have any resources/code that can help with this.

**jltrem - was able to privide me with details for getting the hostname now I just need a bit of help with UserID of the host logged in user if possible....**

Comment: You need to clarify: how do users log it to VM - do they use the same account or different windows user account? Do the users use any additional username to log in to your program?

Comment: These are a stock VM image hosted locally, on each pc, the use the default administrator account, not connected to the network, There is no login associated with my program, it will use the default admin user, I just need to track each time it is launched any by who for network security. The default will be anon read and execute on the network share for this file under the condition I can track who used it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters` for the available host information.  This does require VPC Additions ... without it the VM has no knowledge of the host machine.

Comment: Almost perfect, That obtainst he Phusical hostName, which I do need, is there any way to get the userID of the logged in user...

Comment: Knowledge of the host is unavailable due to security.  VPC Additions lightens this and provides some info.  But it does not provide the host user name.